# Add Multiple Rows NOT Just The Last Row

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue adding multiple rows to the database via a POST form.  Here's a short snippet of the form:

```
<form action='/process.php' method='post'>

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM b_tasks_report WHERE TASK_ID=$taskid GROUP BY WEEK_ID");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$current_weekly_id = $row['WEEK_ID'];
if ($current_weekly_id == 1){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='noborder'>
<input type='hidden' name='productname' value='Week 1 Hours'>
<input type='hidden' name='code' value='232'>
<input type='checkbox' name='wid[]" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "' value='" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "'>Week " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

if ($current_weekly_id == 2){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='noborder'>
<input type='hidden' name='productname' value='Week 2 Hours'>
<input type='hidden' name='code' value='232'>
<input type='checkbox' name='wid[]" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "' value='" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "'>Week " . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

<input style='margin-top: 15px;' type='image' name='submit'>
```

I would like to ensure these two rows are added to the database.  This is the insert I have:

```
$sql="INSERT into b_sale_basket ()
VALUES
('".$_POST['productname']."','".$_POST['code']."','".$_POST['wid']."')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```

This does add the last row but not the first.  I am aware that I need a foreach but I can't get it to work.  I'm stuck on:

foreach($_POST['wid'] as $weekid

before the insert but not having any luck! How do I get it to add both rows as it should do?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: well for starters... `wid[]" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "` should be `wid[" . $row['WEEK_ID'] . "]` notice the brackets positioning

Comment: Ah yes, this is true.  Sorry I missed that.. Starting to get blinded by the code after staring at it for a while.  Thanks but still need a guidance on adding the rows.

Comment: and secondly, if you submit a form with two inputs having the same name as you have `code` and `productname` the second input overrides the first one. You will need to put them into an array as well.

Comment: can you give more of a use case of what you are trying to accomplish and provide some more details concerning database structure with some actual data. According to your code I only see one row that would be inserted for each row that is retrieved from your query. but you still have other issues as well. need more user case please and not just code.